# Seeking an example of using AWS C++ SDK to implement get-credentials-for-identity and it's required get-id input for temporary AWS credentials

Tags: c++, amazon-cognito, aws-sdk-cpp

I am currently building a C++ client which is successfully authenticating to AWS Cognito User Pools.  I wish to obtain temporary AWS credentials via exchanging the received ID token from Cognito.

Using the Advanced Flow with AWS CLI it seems to be two separate calls which I have working.

aws cognito-identity get-id
aws cognito-identity get-credentials-for-identity

The end goal is to receive AccessKeyId,SecretKey,SessionToken,IdentityId for subsequent AWS service calls.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked out the get-id side so the rest will fall easily now.

```
  Aws::SDKOptions options;

Aws::Utils::Logging::LogLevel logLevel{ Aws::Utils::Logging::LogLevel::Error };
options.loggingOptions.logger_create_fn = [logLevel] {return make_shared<Aws::Utils::Logging::ConsoleLogSystem>(logLevel); };

Aws::InitAPI(options);

Aws::Client::ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration;
clientConfiguration.region = REGION;    // region must be set for Cognito operations
s_AmazonCognitoIdentityClient = Aws::MakeShared<Aws::CognitoIdentity::CognitoIdentityClient>("CognitoIdentityClient",clientConfiguration);

Aws::CognitoIdentity::Model::GetIdRequest getIdRequest;
getIdRequest.SetAccountId(AWS_ACCOUNT_ID);
getIdRequest.SetIdentityPoolId(IDENTITY_POOL_ID);

map<string, string> logins{
    {"cognito-idp.[REGION].amazonaws.com/[Your Pool ID]", s_IDToken}
};

getIdRequest.SetLogins(logins);

Aws::CognitoIdentity::Model::GetIdOutcome getIdOutcome{s_AmazonCognitoIdentityClient->GetId(getIdRequest)};
if (getIdOutcome.IsSuccess())
{
    Aws::CognitoIdentity::Model::GetIdResult getIdResult{getIdOutcome.GetResult()};
    cout << "\tIdentity Token: " << getIdResult.GetIdentityId() << endl;

    s_IdentityId = getIdResult.GetIdentityId(); //Set for subsequent call to get credentials

}
else {

    Aws::Client::AWSError<Aws::CognitoIdentity::CognitoIdentityErrors> error = getIdOutcome.GetError();

    cout << "Error logging in: " << error.GetMessage() << endl << endl;
}

Aws::ShutdownAPI(options);
```